# How to include handlebar file into another?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

My views folder structure

```
view
-->layouts
---->main.hbs
-->partials
---->header.hbs
---->footer.hbs
-->pages
---->user
------>includes
-------->list.hbs
---->index.hbs
```

I can import partials files like header and footer in main.hbs
but have no idea about including list.hbs into pages/user/index.hbs.

This is my handlebars configuration

```
const path = require('path');
   const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
   app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '../views'));
   app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
   app.engine(
       'hbs',
        exphbs.engine({
            extname: 'hbs',
            layoutsDir: path.join(__dirname, '../views', 'layouts'),
            partialsDir: path.join(__dirname, '../views', 'partials'),
            defaultLayout: 'main'
        }),
       
   );
```

Comment: Your `pages/user/includes` is just another partial directory, so you will need to register that as an alternative `partialsDir` in your `exphbs.engine` config. See: https://github.com/76484/stackoverflow-72070504/blob/main/server/index.js#L17

Comment: @76484 suppose i have many modules up to 10-15 for that i need to make sub folders like user/includes so is there any optimal way to do this?

Comment: I think "optimal" may be dependent on what you are trying to optimize for. What I would say is that it adds unnecessary complication to introduce a term - "includes" - which looks to be conceptually the same as "partials" - a common, idiomatic Handlebars term. Therefore, I would just put all of the includes in the `partials` directory, perhaps with a subdirectory per page. See: https://github.com/76484/stackoverflow-72070504/tree/main/views/partials